# Finding the square of an unknown variable using a for loop

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to find the square root for an unknown variable using a *for loop*. the prompt I was given is:
So if we passed in 3, you would output 
0^2+1^2+2^2+3^2=14

this is for my intro to scripting class, and I am just at a compete loss.

Comment: at least try to do it....

Comment: your question heading says **square**, and the start of question says **square root** and your example belongs to something else. What exactly do you want?

Comment: for your given example, you can get desired result using `sum((n+1)**2 for i in range(n))` where `n = 3` for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def solve(n):
    res = 0
    for i in range(n + 1):
        res += i ** 2
    return res
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: you definitely help get me started, I had modify your code a little bit to fit the requirement by Codio (the program my school uses for coding classes). so this is what it looks like now:                                                                                                              ( res = 0
for i in range(0, N + 1):
  res += i ** 2
  print (res)  )                                                                                                           the output I'm getting is 0, 1, 5. how can I get it to output a single number with the for loop?

Comment: Put the `print (res)` outside the for loop

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is:

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter number")) # get the number, use input if you are using python 3.x
sum([i**2 for i in range(n+1)]) # form a list with squares and sum them
```

You can do it with lambda too. Here it goes:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + y**2, range(n+1))
```

Comment: also it is worth mentioning that it is `raw_input` for Python 2.x and `input` for Python 3.x